# OpenJPA Transaction Exception

Tags: java, openjpa

I am trying to persist members of a class, BorderPoint. After persisting a certain number of objects, openJPA throws the following exception:

[ERROR]  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to assign id "0" to new instance "org.jason.mapmaker.shared.model.BorderPoint@3134a2" failed; there is already an object in the L1 cache with this id. You must delete this object (in a previous transaction or the current one) before reusing its id.  This error can also occur when a horizontally or vertically mapped classes uses auto-increment application identity and does not use a hierarchy of application identity classes.

The method to persist the BorderPoints accepts a List of BorderPoint objects and attempts to break the persist into batches. Here is the code:

```
public void persistList(List<BorderPoint> objectList) throws RepositoryException {

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        int i = 1;
        for (BorderPoint bp : objectList) {
            em.persist(bp);
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }
            i++;
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (EntityExistsException ex) {
        // need to log this somehow
        //log.warning("persist() threw EntityExistsException: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RepositoryException(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Just for completeness, here is the calling method:

```
/**
 * Cycle through and save the borderpoints saved in the Shapefile's geometry
 *
 * @param featureCollection
 * @throws ServiceException
 */
private void saveBorderPoints(FeatureCollection featureCollection) throws ServiceException {

    FeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        SimpleFeatureImpl feature = (SimpleFeatureImpl) iterator.next();

        String geoId = (String) feature.getAttribute("GEOID10");

        Location location = locationRepository.getByGeoId(geoId);
        if (location == null) {
            throw new ServiceException("saveBorderPoints() threw ServiceException due to null Location");
        }
        MultiPolygon multiPolygon = (MultiPolygon) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
        Geometry geometry = multiPolygon.getBoundary();

        // Create the result list. Set initial capacity size to number of actual points in the geometry to avoid some
        // overhead when dealing with the list
        List<BorderPoint> borderPointList = new ArrayList<BorderPoint>(geometry.getNumPoints());

        // cycle through the coordinates to create the border points
        Coordinate[] coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
        for (Coordinate c : coordinates) {
            BorderPoint borderPoint = new BorderPoint();
            borderPoint.setLocation(location);
            borderPoint.setLng(new BigDecimal(c.x));
            borderPoint.setLat(new BigDecimal(c.y));

            borderPointList.add(borderPoint);
        }

        try {
            borderPointRepository.persistList(borderPointList);
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            throw new ServiceException("saveBorderPoints() threw RepositoryException", e);
        }
    }

    iterator.close();
}
```

Any ideas out there?

EDIT:

Here is the BorderPoint class, as requested:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BORDERPOINT")
public class BorderPoint implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private Location location;
private BigDecimal lat;
private BigDecimal lng;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="LAT")
public BigDecimal getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(BigDecimal lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

@Column(name="LNG")
public BigDecimal getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(BigDecimal lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Location.class)
@JoinColumn(name="LOCATIONID")
public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

Comment: Just by curiosity... have you tried with putting and endTransaction and beginTransaction in the if (i % 100) == 0?

Comment: Where do you assign ids to `BorderPoint`s?

Comment: BTW, adding the BorderPoint with annotations would help a lot (is there an id AUTO?

Comment: axtact: since BorderPoint is an entity, persist() takes care of that. On the database side (currently MySQL *grumble*), the id is an autonumber field.

Comment: Try removing the em.clear() after flush? How are you enhancing your Entities? What version of OpenJPA?

Comment: As Rick pointed out, em.clear() shouldn't be necessary -- OpenJPA will weaken references after the flush() call.